# Material Design Lite: Using Navigation Links in the Drawer UI Element

Tags: material-design-lite

I have added a simple MDL drawer element to the 'Test Template' example (from getmdl.io) and set href='#overview' to link to the 'overview' content page. When clicking the relevant link in the drawer element, nothing happens!  I was expecting the content section to render the 'overview' page similar to clicking the tab in the header section.  Clearly, I must be doing something wrong.  Here is a snippet showing the drawer element and the opening div element of the 'overview' page.

```
...</header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#overview">Overview</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#features">Features</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="overview">...
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

which template is this in getmdl.io please?

I have done this:

```
<body>
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">      
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">Material Design Grid</span>          
            </div>       
        </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Material Design Tutorial</span>
           <nav class="mdl-navigation">
               <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#home">Home</a>
               <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#about">About</a>  
           </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        ...
    </main>
</body>
```

and it's diplaying `#href` on the url and the page remains still.
cross-check your structure with that and if possible, give some more code I check on my end?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have been using the 'Text-only' template (getmdl.io/templates/text-only/index.html) and added the drawer element for test purposes.  The page remains still when I click on the link (from the drawer element).